# Been having this error for a long while on mern stack app, any guidiance will be appreciated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=x.herokuapp.com request_id=d40c155d-9d66-4d1f-91aa-5f1e0354275e fwd="129.205.124.249" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

'like so'

2020-08-27T18:15:44.787593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=x.herokuapp.com request_id=da2fb951-c668-4308-931b-00b9e2ba9f27 fwd="129.205.124.249" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol
2020-08-27T20:55:23.494934+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-dusk-95756.herokuapp.com request_id=88968660-93ca-464d-bf7c-39583d605396 fwd="129.205.113.204" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: what does your error logging tell you? I'm sure you use something like Rollbar or Sentry to try catching what's blowing up your app... no?

Comment: Can you pass us your code repository so we can take a close look?